# Google API callbacks not called

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to connect to the Google Drive API inside an IntentService's onHandleIntent() but connect() doesn't seem to do anything.

None of the callbacks (onConnected, onConnectionSuspended, onConnectionFailed) are being called. No errors or exceptions, just silence.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
     mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

The IntentService implements the callbacks.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is onHandleIntent being called though?

Comment: @noogui, Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

I was able to 'fix' the issue by downgrading to an older version of Google Play services.

I'll leave this open in case someone has an actual fix.